# How to select from only the range of specified characters

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select words that are only within the combination of specified characters.

```
SELECT ph_word FROM `lrrpc` where `plis` like '%[ERNCO]%' AND CHAR_LENGTH(words) < 4
```

The above query is giving me words that contain any of the characters, while I want words only within the characters.

Please is there any suggestion on how to go about?

Comment: Are you sure you are using MySQL?  The `like` expression would only match columns that have square braces.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MySQL, then you can use regular expressions:

```
where plis regexp '^[ERNCO]*$'
```

If you want to check that each letter is used once, then this is trickier.  One method is:

```
where plis like '%E%' and plis not like '%E%E%' and
      plis like '%R%' and plis not like '%R%R%' and
      plis like '%N%' and plis not like '%N%N%' and
      plis like '%C%' and plis not like '%C%C%' and
      plis like '%O%' and plis not like '%O%O%' and
      plis regexp '^[ERNCO]*$'
```

Comment: regexp '^[ERNCO]*$' give even outside the range of  ERNCO, instead of just a permutation of ERNCO